# Sequence converges means it is bounded above and below

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, upper-lower-bounds

What happens in a situation where $\{a_n\}$ has an asymptote, will there ever be a case? Because if there is one then it's no longer bounded.

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence to have an asymptote? I’m only familiar with asymptotes of curves, such as the graph of a function $y=f(x)$.  If it means a line that the points approach, when graphed with the value of $a_n$ as the ordinate and $n$ as the abscissa, then a convergent sequence would have a horizontal asymptote.

Comment: A verticle asymptote*

Comment: A sequence is function from $\mathbb N\to X$.  The domain of the sequence (the set of indexes) is the natural numbers.  It does not make sense to talk of a vertical asymptote if its domain is the natural number where every index is  is exactly one away from the previous index.  It isn't possible to go from $n < a$ and get $n$ "close to" $a$.  The $n$s will always be a distinct integer distance away from $a$ and the concept of a vertical asymptote just won't make sense.

Comment: I was thinking of general terms of a series that would arise issues at a specific index, didn't know a series and a sequence must be defined for all indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence is function from $\mathbb N\to X$.  The domain of the sequence (the set of indexes) is the natural numbers.  It does not make sense to talk of a vertical asymptote if its domain is the natural numbers.

Intuitively to say $f$ has a vertical asymptote at $a$ means that at values "closer and closer" to $a$ that $f(x)$ gets larger and larger.  But if our domain is the natural numbers or integers, taking values "closer and closer" to $a$ just doesn't make sense.

Formally....

A function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ has a vertical asymptote if $\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x) = \infty$.

So if $f(n) =a_n$ so $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$, what does it mean to say $\lim_{n\to a^-} f(x) = \infty$.

By definition it means for any $M$ there is an small number $\delta$ so that if $a-\delta < x < a$ then $f(x) > M$.

That can not be true.  Let $a-1 \le n <a$.  And let $M > f(n)$.

We can't have $\delta > a-n$ because then we'd have $a-\delta < n < a$ but $f(n) < M$.

And we can't have $\delta \le a-n$ because that would mean, if $a-\delta < x < a$ then $x\not \in \mathbb Z$.  So $f(x)$ is not defined and it is not true that $f(x) > M$.

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence is convergent i.e., $\lim s_n = s$ it has a horizontal asymptote $y=s$. Convergent sequence are bounded.

If the asymptote is not horizontal, the sequence is not convergent.

Comment: I forgot to mention the asymptote is verticle,

Comment: It doesn't mean anything for a sequence to have a vertical asymptote. A sequence is a function from the natural numbers to the real numbers. A vertical asymptote won't have a meaning in this context

Comment: Can't there be a situation where plugging in a natural number might give an instance where you divide by 0? I'm guessing such a thing never happens if it converges.

Comment: "Can't there be a situation where plugging in a natural number might give an instance"  Of course not.  That would mean $a_n$ is undefined.  And being a sequence all terms in the sequence are defined.  (Nothing to do with convergence.)

Comment: Ah, I was unaware all terms of a sequence given by a general term MUST be defined. Thank you for clearing up the misconception.

Comment: Every output of a function must be defined.  If something isn't defined it simply does not exist.